# performance of adaptIntegrate vs. integrate

Tags: r, numerical-integration

I'd like to perform a numerical integration in **one dimension**, where **the integrand is vector-valued**. `integrate()` only allows scalar integrands, thus I would need to call it several times. The `cubature` package seems well suited, but it seems to perform quite poorly for 1D integrals. Consider the following example (scalar-valued integrand and 1D integration),

```
library(cubature)
integrand <- function(x, a=0.01) exp(-x^2/a^2)*cos(x)
Nmax <- 1e3
tolerance <- 1e-4

# using cubature's adaptIntegrate
time1 <- system.time(replicate(1e3, {
  a <<- adaptIntegrate(integrand, -1, 1, tol=tolerance, fDim=1, maxEval=Nmax)
}) )

# using integrate
time2 <- system.time(replicate(1e3, {
  b <<- integrate(integrand, -1, 1, rel.tol=tolerance, subdivisions=Nmax)
}) )

time1
user  system elapsed 
  2.398   0.004   2.403 
time2
user  system elapsed 
  0.204   0.004   0.208 

a$integral
> [1] 0.0177241
b$value
> [1] 0.0177241

a$functionEvaluations
> [1] 345
b$subdivisions
> [1] 10
```

Somehow, `adaptIntegrate` seems to be using many more function evaluations for a similar precision. Both methods apparently use Gauss-Kronrod quadrature (1D case: 15-point Gaussian quadrature rule), though `?integrate` adds a "Wynn's Epsilon algorithm". Would that explain the large timing difference?

I'm open to suggestions of alternative ways of dealing with vector-valued integrands such as

```
integrand <- function(x, a = 0.01) c(exp(-x^2/a^2), cos(x))
adaptIntegrate(integrand, -1, 1, tol=tolerance, fDim=2, maxEval=Nmax)
$integral
[1] 0.01772454 1.68294197

$error
[1] 2.034608e-08 1.868441e-14

$functionEvaluations
[1] 345
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't get it sorry; what's wrong with the one-to-one comparison I give for scalar-valued integrand?

Comment: I did test with `fDim=2` (last example, 345 evaluations too), the comparison is merely a case of calling `integrate` twice, `str(lapply(c(integrand1, integrand2), integrate, -1,1, rel.tol=tolerance, subdivisions=Nmax))` gives 10+1 = 11 evaluations. My point being, yes, `adaptIntegrate` targets multi-dimensional integration, and optionally of vector-valued integrands, but the case of one-dimensional integration is much less efficient than calling `integrate` repeatedly, but a large margin (~30 times here).

Comment: Have you seen this package: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R2Cuba/

Comment: I had not, thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @Hemmo care to turn this into an answer and get the bounty before it goes to waste?

Answer (score 3):

There is also [R2Cuba](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R2Cuba) package in CRAN which implements several multidimensional integration algorithms:

I tried to test this with your example function, and in such a simple case I couldn't get all the algorithms to work (although I didn't try really hard), and few methods I did get to work were considerably slower than `adaptIntegrate` with default setting, but perhaps in your true application this package could be worth of trying.