# R integrate: determining number of subdivisions

Tags: r, integrate

I have a function f that given and input produces two numerical vectors x and y of the same length. For my application, I am passing these vectors into aproxfun by calling

```
return(integrate(approxfun(x,y), range(x)[1], range(x)[2], subdivisions = 300))
```

I am executing this process on ~ 1000 different data points. The problem that's occuring is that I keep getting one of two errors:

```
Error in integrate(....): maximum number of subdivisions reached
```

or

```
Error in integrate(...): extremely bad integrand behavior
```

I have found that both of these errors trigger or pass on different inputs depending on the number of subdivisions I choose for each call. I have spent the past three hours through trial and error to try and determine a value in which my entire application will finish. Is there a way to systematically determine a value of subdivisions based on the vectors x and y on each call that will allow integrate to execute? I don't necessarily need the subdivisions to be the same for each call, I just need a good approximation at every instance. Any other information on how integrate works in regard to this process would also be very helpful.

For reference, the values i have tried in order have been: 100, 400, 200, 250, 300

Comment: It's hard to make suggestions without knowing the nature of the curve you are trying to integrate under. Maybe it should be a function of the range? Is your function flat? smooth?

Comment: You might consider trying `adaptIntegrate(...)` from the `cubature` package. It's designed for multiple integrals but will work for 1D integration as well. It's slower (see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924818/performance-of-adaptintegrate-vs-integrate)), but is more robust.

Answer (score 2):

While I wasn't able to find a systematic way to determine appropriate subintervals, I found a workaround for my specific problem using R's try() function. Here's the code detailing what I did:

```
integrateArea = function(myvect, interval = 300) {
  x = seq(0, 300*(length(myvect) - 1), 300)
  y = myvect
  returnvalue = 'a'
  returnvalue = try((integrate(approxfun(x,y), range(x)[1], range(x)[2], subdivisions = 350)))
  if(class(returnvalue) != "numeric") {
    returnvalue = try((integrate(approxfun(x,y), range(x)[1], range(x)[2], subdivisions = 400)))[[1]]
  }
  if(class(returnvalue) != "numeric") {
    returnvalue = try((integrate(approxfun(x,y), range(x)[1], range(x)[2], subdivisions = 300))) [[1]]
  }
  if(class(returnvalue) != "numeric") {
    returnvalue = try((integrate(approxfun(x,y), range(x)[1], range(x)[2], subdivisions = 200))) [[1]]
  }
  if(class(returnvalue) != "numeric") {
    returnvalue = try((integrate(approxfun(x,y), range(x)[1], range(x)[2], subdivisions = 100))) [[1]]
  }
  stopifnot(class(returnvalue) == "numeric")
  return(returnvalue)
}
```

Basically, I tried different values of subdivision until one gave a numeric answer, exploiting the fact that if try fails, it'll produce a list whose first entry is of class character. I use stopifnot to exit in case none of the subdivision cases worked, but it turns out, that between the four cases, my program was able to execute.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post when this error popped out for me. Just wanted to share that the simplest thing i found that works is, obviously increasing the number of subdivisions (because the error is clear that's the problem). And for the bad behaviour, i think smoothing your data and then estimating the function works every time. The problem might be noisy data etc

I almost always use signal::sgolayfilt with very conservative parameters for a quick test.